Do I need a foundation if I want to build a shed on top of paved concrete area?
I have an area next to my driveway that is already paved with concrete.
Can I build my custom shed (6' x 12') directly on top of this concrete, or should I raise up the shed and pour some sort of concrete foundation for the shed to sit on?
I live in California, so there may be some seismic activitiy.
(I checked with local authorities and I don't need a permit for the size of the shed that I'm buildling.)

Most small sheds sit on flat ground.  If people care they have something between the ground/dirt and the shed, a concrete pad/driveway will work.

As long as the concrete is relatively level, it should be no problem.  I don't think I'd worry about a small shed as far as seismic.

First you already have a foundation.    A concrete driveway already has the foundation components you need - assuming it was done right and is relatively flat where you will put the shed.
Second you don't even have to have a formal foundation in almost every state (not sure about California) until you hit over 120 SqFt - bigger than 10x12'.
Third there are traditional standards for building on flat surfaces including concrete pads.    One of the most popular would be sitting your shed on maybe four 4x4s.   This allows for drainage and keeps shed deck out of sitting rain or any other elements.    I think the terms for these are runners but anyway you would normally see these on sheds sitting in dirt - but do it for concrete pads too.    You can throw some rope around the runners and literally move your shed where ever you want.

Are those things called skids?  And is the shed attached to these skids?  I guess that's why you said you can drag it around... Kind of like this?   https://buildblueprint.com/how-to-build-a-shed-foundation-on-skids/

@milesmeow - runners, skidders same thing.

If there are no permits needed (and no utilities that will be run to this shed that would dictate different requirements), then I'd think you'd be fine building it directly on this concrete driveway, assuming the concrete is in good condition.  Generally the purpose of a foundation is to give a good solid base, and if you have a driveway pad already in place, I am guessing that it will be more than sufficient for any weight and stability you'd put in your shed.
